# OpenID login with Google suddenly stopped working in production

Tags: openid, dotnetopenauth

I came in today to find that no one can login to our system that uses DotNetOpenAuth with the Google Provider. This has worked fine for months and there's not been an update to the system in weeks. I'm getting:

```
ERROR DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Provider reports signature verification failed.
```

This is now happening on my local machine as well, does anyone know if something has changed with the Google Provider?

Complete log entry below:

```
2013-04-19 10:45:32,692 (GMT+1) [41] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Http - HTTP GET https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id
2013-04-19 10:45:34,863 (GMT+1) [41] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Yadis - An XRDS response was received from GET at user-supplied identifier.
2013-04-19 10:45:34,864 (GMT+1) [41] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Yadis - Total services discovered in XRDS: 1
2013-04-19 10:45:34,864 (GMT+1) [41] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Yadis - [{
    ClaimedIdentifier: http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select
    ProviderLocalIdentifier: http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select
    ProviderEndpoint: https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud
    OpenID version: 2.0
    Service Type URIs:
        http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/server
        http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0
        http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0/mode/popup
        http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0/icon
        http://specs.openid.net/extensions/pape/1.0
},]
2013-04-19 10:45:34,864 (GMT+1) [41] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Yadis - Skipping HTML discovery because XRDS contained service endpoints.
2013-04-19 10:45:34,865 (GMT+1) [41] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Yadis - Performing discovery on user-supplied identifier: https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id
2013-04-19 10:45:34,865 (GMT+1) [41] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Yadis - Filtering and sorting of endpoints did not affect the list.
2013-04-19 10:45:34,865 (GMT+1) [41] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId - Creating authentication request for user supplied Identifier: https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id
2013-04-19 10:45:34,865 (GMT+1) [41] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId - Could not determine whether OP supported Sreg or AX.  Using both extensions.
2013-04-19 10:45:34,866 (GMT+1) [41] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Preparing to send CheckIdRequest (2.0) message.
2013-04-19 10:45:34,866 (GMT+1) [41] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ExtensionsBindingElementRelyingParty applied to message.
2013-04-19 10:45:34,866 (GMT+1) [41] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.RelyingPartySecurityOptions did not apply to message.
2013-04-19 10:45:34,866 (GMT+1) [41] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.BackwardCompatibilityBindingElement did not apply to message.
2013-04-19 10:45:34,867 (GMT+1) [41] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ReturnToNonceBindingElement did not apply to message.
2013-04-19 10:45:34,867 (GMT+1) [41] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - ReturnTo signed data: 
    dnoa.return_to_sig_handle: lD0z
    dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier: https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id
    ReturnUrl: /

2013-04-19 10:45:34,868 (GMT+1) [41] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ReturnToSignatureBindingElement applied to message.
2013-04-19 10:45:34,868 (GMT+1) [41] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings.StandardReplayProtectionBindingElement did not apply to message.
2013-04-19 10:45:34,868 (GMT+1) [41] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings.StandardExpirationBindingElement did not apply to message.
2013-04-19 10:45:34,868 (GMT+1) [41] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.RelyingPartySigningBindingElement did not apply to message.
2013-04-19 10:45:34,868 (GMT+1) [41] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Prepared outgoing CheckIdRequest (2.0) message for https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud: 
    openid.claimed_id: http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select
    openid.identity: http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select
    openid.assoc_handle: 1.AMlYA9UWwIc6XwY3cBNwCRCb96aKYV7c5ziaDzzlXemScowZoxyJRv1RWXCuoJSd4AEQj_w6m14sSA
    openid.return_to: http://localhost:63854/Account/Logon?ReturnUrl=%2F&dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid&dnoa.return_to_sig_handle=lD0z&dnoa.return_to_sig=HIgme5MYRRBZYU8nkKMW1fM9K6%2BQJreG0OPqatItleY%3D
    openid.realm: http://localhost:63854/
    openid.mode: checkid_setup
    openid.ns: http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0
    openid.ns.sreg: http://openid.net/extensions/sreg/1.1
    openid.sreg.required: 
    openid.sreg.optional: country
    openid.ns.alias3: http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0
    openid.alias3.if_available: alias1,alias2
    openid.alias3.mode: fetch_request
    openid.alias3.type.alias1: http://axschema.org/contact/country/home
    openid.alias3.count.alias1: 1
    openid.alias3.type.alias2: http://schema.openid.net/contact/country/home
    openid.alias3.count.alias2: 1

2013-04-19 10:45:34,868 (GMT+1) [41] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Sending message: CheckIdRequest
2013-04-19 10:45:34,869 (GMT+1) [41] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Http - Redirecting to https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud?openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.assoc_handle=1.AMlYA9UWwIc6XwY3cBNwCRCb96aKYV7c5ziaDzzlXemScowZoxyJRv1RWXCuoJSd4AEQj_w6m14sSA&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A63854%2FAccount%2FLogon%3FReturnUrl%3D%252F%26dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252Faccounts%252Fo8%252Fid%26dnoa.return_to_sig_handle%3DlD0z%26dnoa.return_to_sig%3DHIgme5MYRRBZYU8nkKMW1fM9K6%252BQJreG0OPqatItleY%253D&openid.realm=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A63854%2F&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.ns.sreg=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fextensions%2Fsreg%2F1.1&openid.sreg.required=&openid.sreg.optional=country&openid.ns.alias3=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fsrv%2Fax%2F1.0&openid.alias3.if_available=alias1%2Calias2&openid.alias3.mode=fetch_request&openid.alias3.type.alias1=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2Fcontact%2Fcountry%2Fhome&openid.alias3.count.alias1=1&openid.alias3.type.alias2=http%3A%2F%2Fschema.openid.net%2Fcontact%2Fcountry%2Fhome&openid.alias3.count.alias2=1
2013-04-19 10:46:19,674 (GMT+1) [16] WARN  DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId - Raising minimum OpenID version requirement for Providers to 2.0 to protect this stateless RP from replay attacks.
2013-04-19 10:46:19,675 (GMT+1) [16] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Scanning incoming request for messages: http://localhost:63854/Account/Logon?ReturnUrl=%2F&dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid&dnoa.return_to_sig_handle=lD0z&dnoa.return_to_sig=HIgme5MYRRBZYU8nkKMW1fM9K6%2BQJreG0OPqatItleY%3D&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.mode=id_res&openid.op_endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fud&openid.response_nonce=2013-04-19T09%3A46%3A01ZS6XpwR4ZQavZPg&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A63854%2FAccount%2FLogon%3FReturnUrl%3D%252F%26dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252Faccounts%252Fo8%252Fid%26dnoa.return_to_sig_handle%3DlD0z%26dnoa.return_to_sig%3DHIgme5MYRRBZYU8nkKMW1fM9K6%252BQJreG0OPqatItleY%253D&openid.assoc_handle=1.AMlYA9UWwIc6XwY3cBNwCRCb96aKYV7c5ziaDzzlXemScowZoxyJRv1RWXCuoJSd4AEQj_w6m14sSA&openid.signed=op_endpoint%2Cclaimed_id%2Cidentity%2Creturn_to%2Cresponse_nonce%2Cassoc_handle&openid.sig=ZFvM0jP6No50OcWkMESKqtwO3s1Q5m8DmG3IW5RnpyQ%3D&openid.identity=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid%3Fid%3DAItOawkjhoACXLQwQ3fUFYWcX6-IIBdkkIl2cFk&openid.claimed_id=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid%3Fid%3DAItOawkjhoACXLQwQ3fUFYWcX6-IIBdkkIl2cFk
2013-04-19 10:46:19,675 (GMT+1) [16] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Incoming HTTP request: GET http://localhost:63854/Account/Logon?ReturnUrl=%2F&dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid&dnoa.return_to_sig_handle=lD0z&dnoa.return_to_sig=HIgme5MYRRBZYU8nkKMW1fM9K6%2BQJreG0OPqatItleY%3D&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.mode=id_res&openid.op_endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fud&openid.response_nonce=2013-04-19T09%3A46%3A01ZS6XpwR4ZQavZPg&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A63854%2FAccount%2FLogon%3FReturnUrl%3D%252F%26dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252Faccounts%252Fo8%252Fid%26dnoa.return_to_sig_handle%3DlD0z%26dnoa.return_to_sig%3DHIgme5MYRRBZYU8nkKMW1fM9K6%252BQJreG0OPqatItleY%253D&openid.assoc_handle=1.AMlYA9UWwIc6XwY3cBNwCRCb96aKYV7c5ziaDzzlXemScowZoxyJRv1RWXCuoJSd4AEQj_w6m14sSA&openid.signed=op_endpoint%2Cclaimed_id%2Cidentity%2Creturn_to%2Cresponse_nonce%2Cassoc_handle&openid.sig=ZFvM0jP6No50OcWkMESKqtwO3s1Q5m8DmG3IW5RnpyQ%3D&openid.identity=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid%3Fid%3DAItOawkjhoACXLQwQ3fUFYWcX6-IIBdkkIl2cFk&openid.claimed_id=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid%3Fid%3DAItOawkjhoACXLQwQ3fUFYWcX6-IIBdkkIl2cFk
2013-04-19 10:46:19,676 (GMT+1) [16] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Incoming request received: PositiveAssertionResponse
2013-04-19 10:46:19,676 (GMT+1) [16] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Processing incoming PositiveAssertionResponse (2.0) message:
    openid.claimed_id: https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawkjhoACXLQwQ3fUFYWcX6-IIBdkkIl2cFk
    openid.identity: https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawkjhoACXLQwQ3fUFYWcX6-IIBdkkIl2cFk
    openid.sig: ZFvM0jP6No50OcWkMESKqtwO3s1Q5m8DmG3IW5RnpyQ=
    openid.signed: op_endpoint,claimed_id,identity,return_to,response_nonce,assoc_handle
    openid.assoc_handle: 1.AMlYA9UWwIc6XwY3cBNwCRCb96aKYV7c5ziaDzzlXemScowZoxyJRv1RWXCuoJSd4AEQj_w6m14sSA
    openid.op_endpoint: https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud
    openid.return_to: http://localhost:63854/Account/Logon?ReturnUrl=%2F&dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid&dnoa.return_to_sig_handle=lD0z&dnoa.return_to_sig=HIgme5MYRRBZYU8nkKMW1fM9K6%2BQJreG0OPqatItleY%3D
    openid.response_nonce: 2013-04-19T09:46:01ZS6XpwR4ZQavZPg
    openid.mode: id_res
    openid.ns: http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0
    ReturnUrl: /
    dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier: https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id
    dnoa.return_to_sig_handle: lD0z
    dnoa.return_to_sig: HIgme5MYRRBZYU8nkKMW1fM9K6+QJreG0OPqatItleY=

2013-04-19 10:46:19,676 (GMT+1) [16] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.BackwardCompatibilityBindingElement did not apply to message.
2013-04-19 10:46:19,676 (GMT+1) [16] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Verifying incoming PositiveAssertionResponse message signature of: ZFvM0jP6No50OcWkMESKqtwO3s1Q5m8DmG3IW5RnpyQ=
2013-04-19 10:46:19,676 (GMT+1) [16] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Preparing to send CheckAuthenticationRequest (2.0) message.
2013-04-19 10:46:19,676 (GMT+1) [16] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ExtensionsBindingElementRelyingParty did not apply to message.
2013-04-19 10:46:19,677 (GMT+1) [16] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.RelyingPartySecurityOptions did not apply to message.
2013-04-19 10:46:19,677 (GMT+1) [16] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.BackwardCompatibilityBindingElement did not apply to message.
2013-04-19 10:46:19,677 (GMT+1) [16] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings.StandardExpirationBindingElement did not apply to message.
2013-04-19 10:46:19,677 (GMT+1) [16] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.RelyingPartySigningBindingElement did not apply to message.
2013-04-19 10:46:19,677 (GMT+1) [16] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Prepared outgoing CheckAuthenticationRequest (2.0) message for https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud: 
    openid.return_to: http://localhost:63854/Account/Logon?ReturnUrl=%2F&dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid&dnoa.return_to_sig_handle=lD0z&dnoa.return_to_sig=HIgme5MYRRBZYU8nkKMW1fM9K6%2BQJreG0OPqatItleY%3D
    openid.mode: check_authentication
    openid.ns: http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0
    openid.claimed_id: https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawkjhoACXLQwQ3fUFYWcX6-IIBdkkIl2cFk
    openid.identity: https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawkjhoACXLQwQ3fUFYWcX6-IIBdkkIl2cFk
    openid.sig: ZFvM0jP6No50OcWkMESKqtwO3s1Q5m8DmG3IW5RnpyQ=
    openid.signed: op_endpoint,claimed_id,identity,return_to,response_nonce,assoc_handle
    openid.assoc_handle: 1.AMlYA9UWwIc6XwY3cBNwCRCb96aKYV7c5ziaDzzlXemScowZoxyJRv1RWXCuoJSd4AEQj_w6m14sSA
    openid.op_endpoint: https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud
    openid.response_nonce: 2013-04-19T09:46:01ZS6XpwR4ZQavZPg
    ReturnUrl: /
    dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier: https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id
    dnoa.return_to_sig_handle: lD0z
    dnoa.return_to_sig: HIgme5MYRRBZYU8nkKMW1fM9K6+QJreG0OPqatItleY=

2013-04-19 10:46:19,677 (GMT+1) [16] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Sending CheckAuthenticationRequest request.
2013-04-19 10:46:21,457 (GMT+1) [16] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Http - HTTP POST https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud
2013-04-19 10:46:22,625 (GMT+1) [16] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Received CheckAuthenticationResponse response.
2013-04-19 10:46:22,625 (GMT+1) [16] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Processing incoming CheckAuthenticationResponse (2.0) message:
    is_valid: false
    ns: http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0

2013-04-19 10:46:22,625 (GMT+1) [16] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.BackwardCompatibilityBindingElement did not apply to message.
2013-04-19 10:46:22,625 (GMT+1) [16] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.RelyingPartySigningBindingElement did not apply to message.
2013-04-19 10:46:22,625 (GMT+1) [16] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings.StandardExpirationBindingElement did not apply to message.
2013-04-19 10:46:22,625 (GMT+1) [16] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.RelyingPartySecurityOptions did not apply to message.
2013-04-19 10:46:22,625 (GMT+1) [16] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ExtensionsBindingElementRelyingParty did not apply to message.
2013-04-19 10:46:22,625 (GMT+1) [16] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - After binding element processing, the received CheckAuthenticationResponse (2.0) message is: 
    is_valid: false
    ns: http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0

2013-04-19 10:46:22,625 (GMT+1) [16] ERROR DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Provider reports signature verification failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

From the logs, your RP is misconfigured. It looks like at least when the positive assertion comes back, you instantiate an `OpenIdRelyingParty` with an empty association store (or perhaps none at all), while the instance of `OpenIdRelyingParty` you used to kick off the login did have an association store.

I notice that there is an `openid.assoc_handle` parameter in the request, and that the same value for this parameter is in the positive assertion response. Yet the RP still sends that association handle to the Provider endpoint in a `check_auth` message. That's wrong. And Google is correct to reject it as invalid.

The quickest fix for this is to pass `null` into all `OpenIdRelyingParty` constructors, forcing your RP into "dumb mode" so it stops using shared associations. This should make the final `check_auth` call succeed. Ideally, you'd want to use an association store whose associations are shared across all your servers for this web app (if you're in a web farm) and that you pass in every time you construct an `OpenIdRelyingParty`.

Comment: Thanks for this, I have been passing null for a while, I never got around to using a store. Its using null that has stopped working for us.

Comment: You are *not* passing `null` in all cases, I am pretty certain. Double check please. If you were passing null to the `OpenidRelyingParty` constructors, then your initial authentication request would not include an `openid.assoc_handle` parameter.